# phpstorm and aptana building or synchronizing files slow over network share

Tags: performance, magento, ide, aptana, phpstorm

I've been doing some Magento development over a network share using Aptana and PHPStorm and the syncronizing or project building is extremely slow.

I've tried a few various things to improve speed but no results. PHPStorm takes a few minutes to synchronize the project and Aptana takes even longer to rebulild the project. I've copied the project locally and everything works great.

Is it just more efficient to work on large projects locally? I don't like running xampp or wamp locally. I prefer having a dedicated server and mapping drives to the files.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Locally. Try version control. I recommend git.